# Writing a Simple Math Program

Tags: java

can anyone help me with this java work; i am having difficulties

Write a program to add together the following marks and find the average:
45, 56, 34, 89
Output all the marks, the total (sum) and the average mark.

so far I have done this.

```
public class Average {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        int Average;
        Average = (45 + 56 + 34 + 89) / 4;

        System.out.printin(45 + 56 + 34 + 89) / 4;
    }
}
```

can anybody help me finish this off please ?

Comment: Are you expected to use an array or just a bunch of hard-coded numbers?

Comment: What are you not able to do? Try, you can do this.

Comment: Please use a meaningful title.

Comment: No array just hard coded numbers thanks

Comment: What's the issue? Why create and initialize a variable then ignore it?

Comment: What difficulties are you having?

Comment: Bluej Gives me an error when I try to compile it im very new at coding

Comment: So ... what does the error say??  The point of you doing this exercise is (in part) so that you can get used to *reading and understanding* the error messages!

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: I need help to basically make it run in bluej without any errors so far im up to this point i don't know what else to do

Comment: *"I need help to basically make it run in bluej without any errors so far im up to this point i don't know what else to do"* - First thing to do is to READ the error messages.  Seriously, we could spoon-feed you an answer, but you'd learn nothing from it.

Comment: @user3292912 If you do not know what else to do.. you can never complete this.

Comment: @user3292912 **What are the errors?** When asking a question you need to provide actionable information. Right now you're spelling `println` wrong, and you can't divide the results of calling `println`.

Comment: This seems to be a basic syntax issue and I don't questions related to 'problems generated due to typographical errors' are on-topic here. Read your errors, look at some Java examples and good luck.

Comment: I bassily been learning java for about 2 hours so this is why it may be really bad at this so far I changed it and put this                                                                       
public class Average {
    
    public static void main (String args []){
       
       double Average=(45+56+34+89)/4.0;
       System.out.println (Average);
    
    
    
    
    }

Comment: Thank you people i done it !! thanks alot for everyones help i understand what i done wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

It will be something like rhis:

```
public class Average {
    // Can contain any number of `int` numbers
    static int[] numbers = {45, 56, 34, 88};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance of `Average` class to call non `static` method 

        final double result = new Average().calculateAverage(numbers);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

    }

    double calculateAverage(int[] array) {
        int count = 0; // count of numbers
        int sum = 0;   // count of sum all of numbers 
        for (int currentNumber : array) {
            count++;
            sum += currentNumber;
        }
        // You need to divide by double value to not lost decimal part,
        // so cast `count` to `double`.
        return sum / (double) count;
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
result = 55.75
```

Comment: Yea great ... now he doesn't need to *learn* anything to complete his homework.  (Not least because the chances of him *understanding* your code right now seem pretty small.)

Comment: You know, he can learn by example maybe. I will add comments for better understanding :/

Comment: And that would reduce the chances of him understanding even more!  Hint: look at the level of understanding of Java exhibited by his attempt.

Comment: Yes, I agree the practice is relevant, but to see good and explaining examples also necessary.

Comment: @Shubham - That's unfair.  Maybe he simply has only been taught simple expressions and data types ... so far.

Comment: But hi did it for constant count of numbers and he want to do it for any size of numbers i.e array. Why not?

Comment: thank; you very much but I want to be able to understand what I done wrong this is correct I think but Its completely different to what I started thank you for taking you time to help me just wanted a little help not the whole answer  but thanks you very much

Comment: OK, you calculate your average number for constant count of numbers. In my example I'm using `array` and `for` construction to pass on `not constant` count of numbers: It will be better to start from javadoc, here you will start java learning:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: In your example you will print calculated average like this `System.out.printin(Average)` because you already calculated it in `Average` variable.